# iOS: Random error message from iOS14 EXC_BAD_ACCESS thread Queue: NSManagedObjectContext NSInternalAdditions forgetObject propagateToObjectStore

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Since the new installation iOS 14.0, I have a curious bug that is firing either when I click on a tableview, either when I click on a button, either I open a popover. It is very random, and very hard to reproduce perfectly. The console of xcode is not very talkative about the problem. I have this error message in the thread:

**//BUG EXAMPLE 1**

> #4    0x0000000189c378e8 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _forgetObject:propagateToObjectStore:removeFromRegistry:] ()

And this in the main view:

> Thread 12: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4)

[image: Window1]
[image: Window2]

**//BUG EXAMPLE 2**

[image: Window1]
[image: Window2]

**//BUG EXAMPLE 3**
[image: Window1][image: Window2]

It says that the Thread of the NSManagedObjectContext caused the crash.
[image]
I have problems to get more informations about the bug...

Any ideas?

Comment: Were you expecting to operate a CoreData operation in Main Thread, and somewhat was done in another one (Thread 12) ?

Comment: @Larme I am writing a value in the CoreData, and it is displaying it in the TableView. Or I want to display a popup and it is initialize values in the CoreData. This is two examples

Comment: You should write `yourManagedContext.perform{}` (or `performAndWait()`) to ensure it's called in the correct thread. I think that's the issue.

Comment: That was the problem. I used *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType]* and I should use *NSMainQueueConcurrencyType* instead. Thank you, you saved me lot of time. You can put it in the answer, I will validate it (by adding the piece of code too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error suggested that there was a CoreData action done on a different thread that the one it should.

According to the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext), you can use `perform()` (async) or `performAndWait()` (sync) to ensure that you are doing the calls in the correct queue.

> You use contexts using the queue-based concurrency types in
> conjunction with perform(*:) and performAndWait(*:). You group
> “standard” messages to send to the context within a block to pass to
> one of these methods. There are two exceptions:
>
> Setter methods on
> queue-based managed object contexts are thread-safe. You can invoke
> these methods directly on any thread.
>
> If your code is executing on the
> main thread, you can invoke methods on the main queue style contexts
> directly instead of using the block based API.

> perform(*:) and performAndWait(*:) ensure the block operations are executed on the
> queue specified for the context. The perform(*:) method returns
> immediately and the context executes the block methods on its own
> thread. With the performAndWait(*:) method, the context still executes
> the block methods on its own thread, but the method doesn’t return
> until the block is executed.

When you init your context, it will be attached to some queue, and you won't know which one, but by calling that method (either perform or performAndWait) you'll be sure to do it in the correct one.